# Ionic 3 App got stuck

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

In Ionic 3 app on push to page page getting unresponsive. I am passing navparams to next page . and also making a http call on in next page. This makes netx page unresponsive and whole app became hanged. 
The code for next page is below:

```
export class CategoryProductPage {
  public base_url: string;
  cartCount$: Observable<number>;
  public allProduct: Array<any>;
  category: string;
  catId: string;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public productProvider: ProductsProvider,
    private urlProvider: UrlProvider,
    private cartProvider: CartItemsProvider
  ) {

    this.catId = this.navParams.get('cid');
    this.cartCount$ = this.cartProvider.cartCount;
    this.base_url = this.urlProvider.getUrl();
    if (this.catId) {
      this.getAllProductByCategory(this.catId);
    } else {
      this.getAllProduct();
    }
  }
```

in http call it got stuck whole ionic app.

Comment: I would recommend wd40.

Comment: your problem is most likely not in this piece of code. You could try setting an `alert('1')`, `alert('2')` etc after every line to see where it gets stuck and debug that call

Comment: @Sentinel thanks for reply, what is wd40

Comment: @Ivaro18 thanks for reply, but i am getting API response in Postman client. and in app not getting response for same API call

Comment: Sooooo something is failing before or during you're executing the API call from the app which causes an error and since it's in the constructor, will get your page stuck. Can you show us how you push to this page and set the navParams? And show us what;s happening in `getAllProductByCategory(catId)` and `getAllProduct()`

Comment: btw, since this doesn't use any native cordova plugins, what does your console show you when you run this in the browser? Any errors?

Comment: @aishvarya It can be applied to the network socket to make sure you don't get stuck network packets.

Comment: @Ivaro18 so where i can make api call

Comment: @Ivaro18 in console doesnt show any error

Comment: @Ivaro18 following code to push from home to category product pagegoToCategoryPage(category) {
    this.navCtrl.push('CategoryProductPage', { cid: category });
  }

Comment: public getAllProductByCategory(catId) {
    this.productProvider.getCategoryProduct(catId).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.category = res.data[0].categoryName;
        this.allProduct = res.data[0].products;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
  public getAllProduct() {
    this.productProvider.getAllProduct().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.category = 'ALL Products';
        this.allProduct = res.data;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

Comment: in which lifecycle hooks should i make http call to getb every time refreshed data from server